# Apache a2enmod not found when compiling PHP 7, but is required

Tags: php, apache, compiler-errors, debian

All,

I have compiled and installed Apache 2.2.32 successfully on Debian 8.7, following the directions at http://www.tecmint.com/install-and-compile-php-7-on-centos-7-and-debian-8/ but have received an error when compiling that it can't find a2enmod. Error below:

```
[preparing module 'php7' in /etc/apache2/mods-available/php7.load]
Can't exec "a2enmod": No such file or directory at /usr/bin/apxs line 578. 
'a2enmod php7' failed Makefile:164: recipe for target 'install-sapi' 
failed make: *** [install-sapi] Error 2
```

I have researched this error but most of my a2enmod searches result in finds for enabling ModRewrite for some reason (perhaps there's a link here?!). Anyway, I found the following question asked several months back, but there was no answer posted so I'm trying again:

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38542193/a2enmod-doesnt-exist-when-compiling-apache-but-php7-compile-install-requires-i/42559640#42559640

The compile options are listed in the first link I gave, so I won't repeat them here, but I have followed the document to the letter, and it is using the same major versions of PHP, Apache and Debian as me. I don't know enough about the details of each of these or my platform to understand why this is, but I can't find how to install a2enmod anywhere, and aptitude searches give me nothing.

Can anyone help with this? I am trying to install the most recent version (9) of OwnCloud but I cannot get PHP 7 to compile!

Any help is much appreciated.

Comment: I had a similar problem when I installed the apache2 on Debian. I found the a2enmod was already installed and I just needed to run a2enmod with sudo. A newbee thing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

All,

After much of a headache, the answer appears to be in this article:

https://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/installing-php-7-on-debian-linux-8-jessie-wheezy-using-apt-get/

This tells us how to get the official debian repositories that include PHP 7 added to the apt repositories, then install them from there. This solves my problem by giving me php7, as for why it wasn't compiling itself remains a mystery.

Comment: If this worked and fixed your issue, you can accept it as the correct answer. :) No stigma attached!

Comment: Only valid for Debian 7 or previous, because `a2enmod` was in package `apache2.2-common`. Nevertheless, for Debian 8+ is in `apache2` package.

Answer (score 0):

You need install `a2enmod` binary, which for your Debian version is not in `apache2.2-common`package, but in `apache2`.

So, simply, you have to do:

**Debian 8+**

```
apt-get install apache2
```

**Debian wheezy**

```
apt-get install apache2.2-common
```